# nHibernate only returns an empty row set

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I profile the SQL server and don't see any attempt to hit the server from Hibernate.
Also no errors thrown.
The only thing that happens is Hibernate returns an empty row set.

The query:

```
    var cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.Configure();
    ISessionFactory sesFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    var ses = sesFactory.OpenSession();
    var qry = ses.CreateQuery("from Tko.SmartMoves.Modules.Operations.Domain.vDoors");
    IList<vDoors> x = qry.List<vDoors>();
```

If I set the same thing up using ICriteria I have the same problem.

But this works ~ all other things being equal:

```
    string sql = string.Format("select * from vDoors");
    var cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.Configure();
    ISessionFactory sesFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    var ses = sesFactory.OpenSession();
    var qry = ses.CreateSQLQuery(sql);
    IList<vDoors> x = qry.List<vDoors>();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Probably your class isn't mapped. Querying for an unmapped class returns an empty result set.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  How do I know if my class is mapped/correct if nH doesn't show any information 2 help me understand?  My solution has vDoors.hbm.xml as a embedded resource.  This is the top 3 lines from that file:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="false" assembly="Operations" namespace="Tko.SmartMoves.Modules.Operations.Domain" default-lazy="false">
  <class name ="vDoors" table="dbo.vDoors" dynamic-update="false" lazy="false">  NOTE: I can typo the name of the class in this xml file and nHibernate seems to not even know or care.

Comment: Here is the rest of the vDoors.hbm.xml file 
  <cache usage="read-only"/>
  <id name="DoorId" column="DoorId" type="Int64">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="ParentZoneRecid" />
  <property name="ParentZone" />
  <property name="ParentZoneEnabled" />
  <property name="Zone" />
  <property name="ZoneStatus" />
  <property name="ZoneEnabled" />
  <property name="GenericRecid" />
  <property name="GenericEntity" />
  <property name="GenericName" />
  <property name="GenericEnabled" />
  <property name="GenericType" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

On testing (because of what I posted that was prompted by Oskar Berggren, thank you Oskar) I recognized my vDoors.hbm.xml file was actually named vDoors.xml (without the .hbm.)  I move to suggest the nHibernate crew immediately release a version that throws an error under the circumstance where nHibernate can't find the necessary mapping resource at run-time.

Thanks again Oskar @OskarBerggren